# Conditions for convergence of sequences in quotient topological spaces

Tags: general-topology, reference-request

Let $X$ be a topological space and let $\sim$ be an equivalence relation on $X$. Let $X/_\sim$ be the quotient space, endowed with the quotient topology: a subset $\overline{W} \subseteq X/_\sim$ is open if and only if the counter-image $\pi^{-1}(\overline{W})$ is open in $X$, where $\pi : X \to X/_\sim$ is the canonical quotient map.

Is there a nice characterisation of the convergence of sequences in $X/_\sim$, i.e. a necessary and sufficient condition for a sequence $(\bar{x}_n)$ in $X/_\sim$ to be convergent to an element $\bar{x}$? I'm looking for something like "$\bar{x}_n \to \bar{x}$ if and only if for any $x \in \pi^{-1}(\bar{x})$ there is a sequence $(x_n)$ in $X$ such that $x_n \to x$ in $X$, with $\pi(x_n)=\bar{x}_n$".

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can just rewrite the definition:
$x_n \to x$ in $X/{\sim}$ iff for any neighborhood of $x$ $U$, $⟨x_n⟩$ is eventually in $U$. That is equivalent to $⟨π^{-1}(x_n)⟩$ being eventually in $π^{-1}[U]$ meaning $
(∃n_0) (∀n ≥ n_0): π^{-1}(x_n) ⊆ π^{-1}[U]$.